# Is there a way to detect user agent in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser, user-agent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)
>   [Rails 3: HTTP_USER_AGENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226946/rails-3-http-user-agent)

Is there a way to detect the user agent from a current visitor? I'm currently working on a project to display video files. But for the ipad, iphone / samsung galaxy tab / internet explorer / firefox. I need to display video's is there a solid way to check which browser is visiting my rails app?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you searched before asking this question? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226946/rails-3-http-user-agent).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yep, just use this

```
request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
#or
request.user_agent
```

Comment: I'm not sure that we can call that a "solid way" :p

Answer (score 2):

What about using a simple gem?

[If I remember well, I used this one last time.](http://rubygems.org/gems/user-agent)

> gem install user-agent

[The same one on GitHub](https://github.com/visionmedia/user-agent/tree/1.0.0)

I think that this is a good way to do it...

Comment: LOL there's a gem for that.

Comment: That's a quite old gem which [does not even include Windows 8](https://github.com/tj/user-agent/blob/1.0.0/lib/user-agent/agent.rb#L121), and it has only one single release on RubyGems. I would suggest `useragent` with operating system support up to [Windows 10](https://github.com/gshutler/useragent/blob/v0.16.7/lib/user_agent/operating_systems.rb#L6).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it also client site with jquery ... there is a plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/client-detect