# Detect user agent in Rails 4 - read HTTP header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-4, user-agent

I just switched from PHP to Ruby on Rails and was wondering if there was a way to detect the clients device/user agent (reading the HTTP header) in order to serve different versions of the site depending on the request it gets. In PHP I have been using [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) to do so. The general idea is to only serve files that are needed for each particular version. Thats why a client side approach is not that effective.

Is there a way to do something similar with Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0 ?

Maybe there is a gem to handle cases like that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650799/is-there-a-way-to-detect-user-agent-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Check the [request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#method-i-request) method, where you can get a [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) where you have all the request parameters, including the user agent.

```
request.user_agent
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't see this helpful tip mentioned on either of your two links any more.

Comment: The `user_agent` helper is defined in the [`Rack::Request::Helpers` module](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request/Helpers#user_agent-instance_method) (which is included in `Action::Dispatch::Request`)