# Ruby on Rails: Logging server URL requests to a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

So I have a web service and I need to log URL requests to that service to a file. It should be formatted as [resource] [browser], for example like this:

```
    /photo/23 firefox
    /photo/23 chrome
    /photo/24 chrome
    /user/1 ie9
    /user/2 ie9
    /photo/67 chrome
```

My web service is written in Ruby on Rails, so I am wondering how to achieve this behaviour. What gem to use, where to put logger logic etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a gem. You can add before_action hook in your application_controller.rb :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :log_actions

  def log_actions
    logger.debug "#{request.path} #{request.user_agent}"
  end
end
```

NOTE 1: `logger.debug` will log by default in the `log/development.log` file if you are in development. You can write in any other file if you like.

NOTE 2: `request.path` gives you the resource path alone (eg. `/photo/23`). If you also want to include the GET parameters with `request.fullpath` (eg. `/photo/23?page=1`)

NOTE 3: `request.user_agent` gives a full description of the user agent which is long:

```
eg. Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86
```

You can make it shorter with regex as described here:

[Rails 3: HTTP_USER_AGENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226946/rails-3-http-user-agent)

example:

```
def shortbrowser(mybrowser)
  case mybrowser 
    when /MSIE/ then "Internet Explorer"
    when /Chrome/ then "Chrome"
    ...
    else mybrowser
  end
end
```

Then use it:

```
logger.debug "#{request.path} #{shortbrowser(request.user_agent)}"
```